# Is it possible to use the L'hopital rule for computing the derivative of this function at x=0?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

The function
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases} \cos(1/x) & x\neq 0\\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}.
\end{equation}

and the function $F(x)=\displaystyle \int ^x_0 f $

And I know that by considering another function $g(x)$, it's possible to solve that $F'(0)=0$

However, I wonder why I can't use the L'hopital rule for this question.

More specifically, If I want to find the derivative of $F(x)$ at $x=0$, based on the definition of the derivative, I can use

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{F(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\displaystyle \int ^x_0 f }{x}=F'(0)$ and since this is a $0/0$, then I use the L'hopital rule to the nominator and the denominator.

The result will be $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \cos \frac{1}{x}$ which indicates that $F'(0)$ doesn't exist.

I wonder why this is a wrong procedure, I kind of doubt that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\int^x_0 \cos \frac{1}{x}$ is not 0. Is this true? Or are there some other problems with this?

Comment: I think L'Hôpital's rule says that **if** $f'/g'$ has a limit, then $f/g$ has the same limit, but it doesn't say anything when $f'/g'$ doesn't have a limit.

Comment: You could perhaps integrate by parts by saying that $f = x^2 \frac{1}{x^2}\cos(1/x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule says (under some assumptions) that **if** $f'/g' \to A$, then $f/g \to A$. In your case $f'/g'$ doesn't tend to anything, so the rule simply doesn't apply.